# How can I make Django template correctly in Bootstrap5 nav-tabs?

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-5

Hi I'm new to stackoverflow. I want some help to make Django templates correctly appear in Bootstrap5 nav-tab.

I embedded Django HTML template in Bootstrap5 nav-tab as following, but it doesn't apper up when I render the page. I want each tab to contain dynamically generated HTMLs by Django and to correctly show them.

Does anyone have an idea to make this work? Any helps would be apprciated. Thanks!

```
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab"
                        aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Abstract</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab"
                        aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Questions</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab"
                        aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">FAQ</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
                ...
                </div>
                
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                    {% for item in question_list %}
                     {{ item.question_id }}
                    {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The code you've posted should work fine. Make sure you're django template is properly referencing/including bootstrap.js

Comment: Zim, thank you very much! And you were right, that code worked fine after I configured my views.py correctly.